# Is there any way to focus a component when changing pages through Link or history ( react-router-dom )?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-router

**Goal**

I want to be able to focus on a component when page changes through a Link or find some other way to render the page on initial scroll state

**Problem**

My application has two pages, both have scroll, if I scroll down on page 1 and click a Link, or a component with history.push, the page 2 is rendered, but not in the initial scroll state, is rendered in the same position as I was on page 1, all down.

**Question**

I understand that i'm at the same page, and the router just render other page/component, but how deal with it on SPA's? on React ?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your code, the router, routes, and routed components. It basically sounds like you need to implement *some* ["scroll to top" functionality](/a/70181074/8690857).

Comment: Do you want to always scroll to top, or scroll to a specific element?

Comment: @DrewReese exactly.  Only the instant attribute i believe does not exist anymore.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't appear to exist now. Thanks. I've updated.